# Learning resources for Couchapp, Mustache.js, Evently, CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, mustache, couchapp

What are some of the good learning resources that you have come across aiding your application development in CouchApp stack including Evently and Mustache.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi-part series on using: [jQueryMobile and CouchApp](http://custardbelly.com/blog/jqm-couchdb/)

Comment: Haven't looked at it in a while, but it seems like he's broken it out into multiple parts, starting here: https://www.custardbelly.com/blog/blog-posts/2010/12/08/jquery-mobile-couchdb-part-1-getting-started/index.html

Answer (score 2):

In my endeavour of searching and discovering for the materials here are some that I found.

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-couchapp/?ca=drs-
- http://blog.couchbase.com/
- http://couchapp.org/page/evently-do-it-yourself
- http://mustache.github.com/#demo

Couldn't find more. Should I find more I'll keep this one updated. Hope it helps!